# lxml etree and xpath returning an encoded image rather than URL for src

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, html-parsing, lxml

I want the src url of an image when I process some html, but I am getting back an encoded image. What am I doing wrong if I want the url?

Given a url like: "[http://www.amazon.com/Cheese-Plate-multi-purpose-mounting-plate/dp/B00CI06DWE/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CI06DWE)"

And a desktop user agent:

```
from lxml import etree
import requests

page = requests.get(url, headers=agent)
page_txt = page.text

html_parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(page_txt), html_parser)

path = '//img[@id="landingImage"]'

img = tree.xpath(path)

img_src = img[0].get('src')
```

using that code, I'm getting back:

'\ndata:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR'(truncated)

when I want:

[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41SNmVfXvhL.*SY355*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41SNmVfXvhL._SY355_.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [base64 encoded image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images) in the `src` attribute. You can get the actual URL from the `data-a-dynamic-image` attribute, it contains JSON string with url inside:

```
import json 

path = '//img[@id="landingImage"]/@data-a-dynamic-image'
print next(json.loads(tree.xpath(path)[0]).iterkeys())
```

Prints:

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41SNmVfXvhL._SX466_.jpg
```